# Unable to insert into two different tables with help of transactions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, transactions

Below is a my code write up in which i am trying to insert data into two different tables with help of transactions but code is not executing. Trying very hard to find out issue but unable to resolve it.

I am getting this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''u_id_fk','device_type','ip_num','package','pkg_id_fk') VALUES('79','abc','128.1' at line 1[]

```
                $cust_name = 'multi';
                $u_name = 'multi2';
                $cnic_num = '421';
                $address = 'sadaddd';
                $password = md5('423423'); 
                $cellnum='43243';
                $p_id_fk=(int)'3';



                    try {
                            // First of all, let's begin a transaction
                            $conn->beginTransaction();
                            // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
                            // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
                             // Forgot to close the VALUES bracket and couldn't find your $email
                            $users_stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`cust_name`, `u_name`, `cnic`, `address`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (:cust_name, :u_name, :cnic, :address, :password, :email)");
                            // PDO::execute() can accept an array of parameter bound to your query so you may avoid selecting data type when using bindParam()
                           $users_stmt->execute(["cust_name"=>$cust_name, "u_name"=>$u_name, "cnic"=>$cnic_num, "address"=>$address, "password"=>$password, "email"=>$email]);
                            // Not sure if $db is a PDO object...
                            $connections_stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO connections('u_id_fk','device_type','ip_num','package','pkg_id_fk') VALUES(:u_id_fk,:device_type,:ip_num,:package,:pkg_id_fk)");
                            $connections_stmt->execute(["u_id_fk"=>$u_id,"device_type"=>$device_type,"ip_num"=>$ip_num,"package"=>$package,"pkg_id_fk"=>$p_id_fk]);


                            $conn->commit();
                        } catch (Exception $e) 
                        {
                            // An exception has been thrown
                            // We must rollback the transaction
                            $conn->rollback();
                            echo $e;
                        }
```

Please help to resolve it! Thanks

Comment: Do you have errors after execution?

Comment: Catch block is not showing any error just browser is giving http error 500

Comment: Have you tried saving without using transaction for testing only?

Comment: You can try to use `if` to check if your statement is executed correctly,  `$stmt` - Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. Check this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Have you checked a server error log?

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look on it. Thanks

Comment: Where is the $package variable? also no need for typecasting here $p_id_fk=(int)'3';  instead write $p_id_fk=3;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important to set PDO error mode to EXCEPTION during connection.

Avoid using simple hashing algorithms for password as it can be extracted using Rainbow Attack.

```
$cust_name = 'multi';
$u_name = 'multi2';
$cnic_num = '421';
$address = 'sadaddd';
$password = md5('423423'); 
$cellnum='43243';
$p_id_fk=(int)'3';

try {
    // DB vars
    $db_host="";
    $db_name="";
    $db_username="";
    $db_password="";

    // Create a new PDO connection and set error mode to EXCEPTION
    $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_host.";dbname=".$db_name,$db_username,$db_password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    $conn->beginTransaction();

    // Forgot to close the VALUES bracket and couldn't find your $email
    $users_stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`cust_name`, `u_name`, `cnic`, `address`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (:cust_name, :u_name, :cnic, :address, :password, :email)");
    // PDO::execute() can accept an array of parameter bound to your query so you may avoid selecting data type when using bindParam()
    $users_stmt->execute(["cust_name"=>$cust_name, "u_name"=>$u_name, "cnic"=>$cnic_num, "address"=>$address, "password"=>$password, "email"=>$email]);
    $connections_stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO connections(`u_id_fk`,`device_type`,`ip_num`,`package`,`pkg_id_fk`) VALUES(:u_id_fk, :device_type, :ip_num, :package, :pkg_id_fk)");
    $connections_stmt->execute(["u_id_fk"=>$u_id, "device_type"=>$device_type, "ip_num"=>$ip_num, "package"=>$package, "pkg_id_fk"=>$p_id_fk]);

    $conn->commit();
} catch (Exception $e){ 
    $conn->rollback();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Hi, i modified your code according to your answer, but it is giving me a error. I have updated my code in question. Please have a look on it. Thanks

Comment: Please don't echo the error message.

Comment: What is disadvantage of echoing the error message?

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi You are getting that error because you enclosed your column names in single quotation mark (') instead of backticks or grave accent (`). I've updated my answer to resolve that error.

Answer (score 0):

The closing double quotation in your first statement is not correct, it must be at the end of it and also you missed the end  bracket of prepare function

```
 $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (cust_name, u_name,cnic,address,password,email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Try to correct that typo.

Comment: I have corrected the typo error but still it is not working. I think i should post link to whole php file so that it would be easy to track the error. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VbkW1IfsaC40ZfXISbpIQqn2UIu3oHnq